# MonoTouch: does it support MEF?

Tags: xamarin.ios, mef, xamarin.android

I am trying to port an existing c# .net application that is using MEF extensively to MonoTouch and MonoDroid.  Does MonoTouch and MonoDroid support MEF?

Comment: Define "support"?  If you mean can MEF work with MonoTouch and MonoDroid--why don't you try it and find out?  Seriously I doubt that anyone from Novell will be able to give you a definitive answer so you're probably better off to try it yourself and see if it works or not.  Or if you're seeing some specific problem that's making you question whether or not MEF is supported then edit your question to tell us the specific issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try using [PocketMEF](http://pocketmef.codeplex.com/).

It is a subset of MEF that can run on PocketPC, WindowsCE, etc.

You will have to create a MonoTouch project from the source, because I would think there would be some minor changes to make it run in MonoTouch.

All the attributes and classes are named the same as standard MEF, you should only have to change a reference and a using statement with `#if iPhone` to get it working.

Answer (score 0):

According to the list of [MonoTouch assemblies](http://monotouch.net/Documentation/Assemblies) and [Monodroid assemblies](http://mono-android.net/Documentation/Assemblies), the MEF assembly (`System.ComponentModel.Composition.dll`) is not included.

It might still be possible to compile the [MEF sources](http://mef.codeplex.com/SourceControl/list/changesets) for these platforms, but this would probably require modifications to eliminate unavailable dependencies.